# React hook form popular form with Material UI

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form

I am trying to use react hook form with Material UI. At first, I want to populate the fields(textboxes, selects, autocompletes) after I fetch the user profile. How can I do that?

```
const [profileData, setProfileData] = useState(null);
const { control, handleSubmit, register, reset } = useForm();

useEffect(() => {
  const getProfileData = async () => {
    try {
      const data = await api.get(profiles.getById, { id: profileId });
      setProfileData(data);
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(`error getting: ${err}`);
    }
  };

  getProfileData();
}, [profileId]);

<form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
  <Flexbox flexDirection="column">
    <Flexbox className="form-item">
      <Select name="title" value={currentProfile.email}>
        {dummyData.namePrefixes.map(index => (
          <MenuItem key={index}>{index}</MenuItem>
        ))}
      </Select>
      <TextField
        inputRef={register}
        name="Name"
        label="* Name"
        InputLabelProps={{
          shrink: true
        }}
        variant="outlined"
        placeholder="Name"
        className="form-item-full"
      />
    </Flexbox>
    <TextField
      inputRef={register}
      label="* Hospital Name"
      name="hospital"
      className="form-item"
      placeholder="Hospital"
      InputLabelProps={{
        shrink: true
      }}
      variant="outlined"
    />
    <Autocomplete
      className="form-item"
      options={countries}
      getOptionLabel={option => option.name}
      renderInput={params => (
        <TextField
          {...params}
          label="Country"
          placeholder="Select a Country"
          InputLabelProps={{
            shrink: true
          }}
          variant="outlined"
        />
      )}
    />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const [profileData, setProfileData] = useState(null);
const { control, handleSubmit, register, reset } = useForm();

useEffect(() => {
  getProfileData();
}, []);

const getProfileData = async () => {
    try {
      const data = await api.get(profiles.getById, { id: profileId });
      setProfileData(data);
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(`error getting: ${err}`);
      setProfileData(null);
    }
  };

return (
   <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
  
      <TextField
        inputRef={register}
        name="Name"
        label="* Name"
        InputLabelProps={{
          shrink: true
        }}
        value={profileData?.name}
        variant="outlined"
        placeholder="Name"
        className="form-item-full"
      />
    
    <TextField
      inputRef={register}
      label="* Hospital Name"
      name="hospital"
      className="form-item"
      placeholder="Hospital"
      InputLabelProps={{
        shrink: true
      }}
      value={profileData?.hospitalName}
      variant="outlined"
    />

    </form>
)
```